# Object to array bug

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

So I wrote this function to convert an object to an array.

Function:

```
function objectToArray(obj) {
    const result = [];
    
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
            result[key] = objectToArray(value);
        } else {
            result[key] = value;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Object that I try to convert:

```
const obj = {
    "1129931367": {
        "id": 10,
        "amount": 1,
        "assets": {
            "appid": 252490,
            "app_name": "name",
            "classid": 1129931367,
            "icon_url": "url",
            "tradable": 1,
            "name": "name",
            "market_name": "market name",
            "market_hash_name": "market hash name",
            "sell_listings": 3215,
            "sell_price": "0.10",
            "updated_at": "17-Dec-2022"
        },
        "market_tradable_restriction": 7,
        "market_marketable_restriction": 7,
        "tags": [
            {
                "category": "category",
                "internal_name": "internal name",
                "localized_category_name": "localized category name",
                "localized_tag_name": "localized tag name"
            },
            {
                "category": "category",
                "internal_name": "internal name",
                "localized_category_name": "localized category name",
                "localized_tag_name": "localized tag name"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Output:

```
(1129931368) [empty × 1129931367, Array(0)]
```

But when I try to convert the object that I want to convert it adds a lot of empty arrays and I don't know why. Is this because there is something wrong with the Object or with my function?

Thanks for the help :D

I have tried rewriting the function I provided multiple times but this is as close as I got to what I want.

Comment: What is the expected output? `result` is an array and you are updating `result[key]` instead of pushing into the array. When you add the index `1129931367`, the array length becomes 1129931368.

Comment: "*convert an object to an array*" this premise doesn't really make much sense. There is no apparent reason to do that. The object is obviously not representable by an array. So, the conversion is just taking an object and smashing all its properties to an array which...gives you a worse object at the end. What are you really after, since what you have right now seems just like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not using the `push` functionality.

`result[key] = value;` is essentially pushing to the array in that position.

Instead you need:

```js
function objectToArray(obj) {
    const result = [];
    
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
            // push a spread of the array, this avoids nesting arrays
            result.push(objectToArray(value));
        } else {
            result.push(value);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

const initial = {
    "1129931367": {
        "id": 10,
        "amount": 1,
        "assets": {
            "appid": 252490,
            "app_name": "name",
            "classid": 1129931367,
            "icon_url": "url",
            "tradable": 1,
            "name": "name",
            "market_name": "market name",
            "market_hash_name": "market hash name",
            "sell_listings": 3215,
            "sell_price": "0.10",
            "updated_at": "17-Dec-2022"
        },
        "market_tradable_restriction": 7,
        "market_marketable_restriction": 7,
        "tags": [
            {
                "category": "category",
                "internal_name": "internal name",
                "localized_category_name": "localized category name",
                "localized_tag_name": "localized tag name"
            },
            {
                "category": "category",
                "internal_name": "internal name",
                "localized_category_name": "localized category name",
                "localized_tag_name": "localized tag name"
            }
        ]
    }
}

console.log(objectToArray(initial))
```

EDIT: Removed the spread operator to add depth

Comment: This makes an array of every key and value from the object. I want it so it keeps the depth /nesting from the object

Comment: @JasperErkel no problem, see edit, I have removed the spread operator and now the flattening had been removed

Comment: So close but I would like to keep the keys from the object. So you would get somethin glike this: "1129931367": [ "id": 10, "amount": 1, "assets": [ etc,

Answer (score 0):

You could take only the values and take flatMap for a flat result.

```js
function objectToArray(object) {
    return Object
        .values(object)
        .flatMap(value => value && typeof value === 'object'
            ? objectToArray(value)
            : value
        );
}

const obj = { "1129931367": { id: 10, amount: 1, assets: { appid: 252490, app_name: "name", classid: 1129931367, icon_url: "url", tradable: 1, name: "name", market_name: "market name", market_hash_name: "market hash name", sell_listings: 3215, sell_price: "0.10", updated_at: "17-Dec-2022" }, market_tradable_restriction: 7, market_marketable_restriction: 7, tags: [{ category: "category", internal_name: "internal name", localized_category_name: "localized category name", localized_tag_name: "localized tag name" }, { category: "category", internal_name: "internal name", localized_category_name: "localized category name", localized_tag_name: "localized tag name" }] } };

console.log(objectToArray(obj));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```